# React-Flux Load initial state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux, axios

I'm trying to make an Ajax request in al React Flux app with axios and I get data after state is set.

I have this code in root app:

```
InitialData.getInitialPosts();
```

The API request it looks like this:

```
let PostsApi = {
    getAllPosts(){
        return axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
            .then( (response) => {
                console.log('All posts: ', response.data)
                return response.data;
        });
    }
}

export default PostsApi;
```

In actions/initialData.js i have this:

```
let LoadInitialData = {
    getInitialPosts(){
        Dispatcher.dispatch({
            actionType: 'LOAD_INITIAL_POSTS',
            initialPosts: {
                posts: PostsApi.getAllPosts()
            }
        })
    }
}

export default LoadInitialData;
```

In store:

```
let _posts = [];
const PostsStore = Object.assign({}, EventEmitter.prototype, {

    addChangeListener(callback){
        this.on('change', callback)
    },

    removeChangeListener(callback){
        this.removeChangeListener('change', callback)
    },

    emitChange(callback){
        this.emit('change', callback)
    },

    getAllPosts(){
        return _posts;
    }
});

Dispatcher.register(function(action){

    switch(action.actionType){
        case 'LOAD_INITIAL_POSTS':
            _posts = action.initialPosts.posts;
            PostsStore.emitChange();
            break;

        default:
    }

});
```

In View:

```
export default class PostsPage extends React.Component {

    constructor(){
        super();

        this.state = {
            posts: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.setState({
            posts: PostsStore.getAllPosts()
        });
    }

    render(){        
        const { posts } = this.state;
        return(
            <div>
                {posts.map( post => {
                    return <h3 key={post.id}>{post.title}</h3>
                })}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

On console.log:

> state:  Object {posts: Array[0]}
>
> state:  Object {posts: Promise}
>
> postsApi.js:7 All posts:  [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object...]

And the problem is the ajax request is after `componentDidMount`.

Comment: There's not enough information here.  What did you want to have happen?  What happened instead?  Where is the relevant code that shows the point at which it fails?

Comment: I give you more information , thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your `PostsPage` component is not set up correctly to listen to changes from the store.  The code you have will only grab the list of posts *once* when it first mounts.  You want it to update whenever the Store gets new data.

To accomplish this, you need to utilize the add/remove Change Listener functions that you setup in the Store.  It should look something like this;

```
export default class PostsPage extends React.Component {

    constructor(){
        super();

        this.state = {
            posts: []
        }
    }

    _calculateState(){
        this.setState({
            posts: PostsStore.getAllPosts()
        });
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        PostsStore.addChangeListener(this._calculateState);
    },

    componentWillUnmount(){
        PostsStore.removeChangeListener(this._calculateState);
    },

    render(){        
        const { posts } = this.state.posts;
        return(
            <div>
                {posts.map( post => {
                    return <h3 key={post.id}>{post.title}</h3>
                })}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```